# Dropdown with custom string, how to retrive original object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Note: The Add method I'm using is an extension method - hopefully doesn't impact on the questions below.

I have a resource object with two string properties among others. 
The resource object is pulled using an SQL query from an MS SQL DB.
I want to list these objects in a drop down, but displaying these properties in a custom way (i.e. not the .ToString() result).

This is how I populate the dropdown:

```
private void PopulateResourceDropDowns()
{
  lstResources.Items.Clear();
  lstResources.Items.Add("---Select---", Guid.Empty);

  if (Agent != null) {
    IEnumerable<Resource> res_list = Agent.Resources;
    foreach (Resource res in res_list) {
      lstResources.Items.Add(res.companyID + " :: " + res.Name, res.ID);
    }        
  }
}
```

I'm not totally familiar with IEnumerables and am worried that the above implementation is resulting in a SQL query call on each pass of the foreach loop. 
Am I correct in using an enumerable in this instance? Or should I use a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle this type of task using list consist of class like

Class

```
public Class A
{
   public int EmployeeId{set;get;}
   public string EmployeeName{set;get;}
}
```

Data retrive and data Binding

```
List<A> objList=new List<A>();
objList=getData(); // retvire data from database 

lstResources.DataSource=objList;
lstResources.DataTextField="EmployeeName";
lstResources.DataValueField ="EmployeeId";
lstResources.DataBind();
lstResources.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("--Select--","0"));
```

things becomes so much easy .

Comment: thank you for the answer Anik. I take it you recommend using a List. , but won't your code above just display the employee name?

Comment: yes but if you send suppose EmployeeName= EmployeeName + EmployeeId from data retrive part it will show employeename along with employee id